# @dataProvider in Cest format in Codeception

Tags: php, unit-testing, codeception

How shall I use "@dataProvider" in Cest format? (http://codeception.com/docs/05-UnitTests#Cest)
For example I have this code. How to write it in Cest format

```
class ExampleTest extends \Codeception\TestCase\Test
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider providerAdd
     */
    public function testAdd($a, $b, $c)
    {
        $this->assertEquals($c, ($a + $b));
    }

    public function providerAdd()
    {
        return array (
            array (2, 2, 4),
            array (2, 3, 5),
            array (3, 5, 8)
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Codeception 2.2 there is a better alternative, using 'examples':
http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#examples

This is a Cest-style implementation of what you know as dataProviders in unit/functional tests. It currently only allows to supply data sets in annotations, but it's workable...

Answer (score 2):

The @data**p**rovdier annotation works for me now in Codeception as the docs on the website (or docs/07-AdvancedUsage.md) - but please note the annotation is case sensitive @data**p**rovdier not @dataProvdier.

http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage#Cest-Classes

Answer (score 0):

`@dataProvider` is a [PHPUnit annotation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html) which isn't evaluated in the Cest or Cept execution.

If you want to write tests in a TDD/BDD fashion you can follow [the Codeception guidelines](http://codeception.com/docs/05-UnitTests#BDD-Specification-Testing). Also, Specify supports [examples](https://github.com/Codeception/Specify#examples) which can replace the use of php annotations.

Comment: Do you happen to know if the Cest format still doesn't support @dataProvider? The docs here seem to indicate it can but it doesn't seem to work? http://codeception.com/docs/07-AdvancedUsage

Comment: WFM now! Dived into all the Codeception DI but it was just case sensitivity in my annotation @data**p**rovider works (Codeception 2.2.9).